# select min values of time for each date in a range and getting the average in oracle

Tags: oracle, time, average

I have a table in oracle user_transn(userid, resourceid, transid, act_timestamp) with values like

```
    (21, 14, 123321, 28-NOV-11 13:30:21)
    (21, 14, 123321, 28-NOV-11 14:29:28)
    (21, 14, 123321, 29-NOV-11 18:44:22)
    (21, 14, 123321, 30-NOV-11 11:30:55)
    (21, 14, 123321, 30-NOV-11 16:56:11)
    (21, 14, 123321, 30-NOV-11 19:32:31)
    (21, 14, 123321, 31-NOV-11 09:22:51)
    (21, 14, 123321, 31-NOV-11 12:22:49)
    (21, 14, 123321, 31-NOV-11 13:11:17)
    (21, 14, 123321, 31-NOV-11 16:41:21)
```

The  query should take the minimum time of the act_timestamp field of each distinct date and calculate the average minimum time over the given date range (which in this case is 28-31 nov)

So for above the result should be: 13:30:21 + 11:30:55 + 9:22:51  /3  = 11:27:42
as the average min time

and similarly for max time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you ignore `29-NOV-11 18:44:22` ?

Comment: Also, which calendar allows 31 days in November?

Comment: And your example is wrong. The average of your three values is `11:28:02`, not `11:27:42`.

Comment: What have you attempted when trying to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Select `min_timestamp`, calculate the average of the time-part, and add the current day to convert back to a date:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + AVG(min_timestamp - TRUNC(min_timestamp)), 'HH24:MI:SS')
FROM
(
  SELECT MIN(act_timestamp) AS min_timestamp
  FROM user_transn
  GROUP BY TRUNC(act_timestamp)
)
```